# How to advertise phone as a different device using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, bluetooth

I am trying to program an app that allows my phone to show up as a different device during the Bluetooth pairing process so I can play around with the different drivers on my computer. However, I'm not sure where to begin. Is there any way to accomplish this, like with a custom Bluetooth Profile? Or is there a way to broadcast my phone as a Bluetooth mouse during the discovery phase of the connection process?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :D

Comment: You certainly can't do this on iOS

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but my answer may not fit your needs at all.

The Bluetooth device name cannot be changed programmatically, to change your device's name you'll go to settings (About device / Bluetooth) and change the name.

The device type (phone, computer, wireless speakers) cannot be changed unless you modify the Bluetooth adapter (you'll need to root your device if you're using Android) or the driver (if you're using Bluetooth from PC). I don't know how to change that, but doing that will possibly be very difficult and isn't worth it.

The Bluetooth address can be changed by spoofing.